# Published application not showing in developers link

Tags: android, publish

I published my new application 16 hours ago.

I can see my application only by visiting the direct link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=development.nk.cretanrecipes

The problem is that i can not see my application in my developer's link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=NKdevelopment

In addition to that my app is not indexed, so nobody can find my app by searching it...

Should i wait a few more hours or i have done something wrong? Should i contact google ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play can be notoriously slow, both for the Developer Console and the Front End for users.

I've seen apps go live and not turn up on my Developer page for close to 48 hours. There is no way you did anything wrong, as Google Play doesn't provide any option for you to omit apps from your developer page which you may have accidentally enabled.

I'd recommend waiting for a day or two more. If it still doesn't turn up, you could *try* contacting Google Play support, but I wouldn't get my hopes high about even receiving a response.